# How to pass Dictionary<Guid,int> to an ASP.NET Core MVC action through an Ajax call?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this function:

```
reloadCartComponent() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Products/UpdateCart",
        data: {
            o: "Roman"//what type of object will be bound to Dictionary<Guid, int> on the controller's side
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#summary").html(data);
        }
    })
}
```

And this action method in my controller:

```
public IActionResult UpdateCart(Dictionary<Guid, int> quantityDictionary = null)
{
    return ViewComponent(typeof(CartComponent), quantityDictionary);
}
```

The method is being called but I have no idea what object I should build on the script side that is going to be correctly converted into `Dictionary<Guid, int>` on the controller side.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
  public IActionResult UpdateCart(Dictionary<Guid,int> productQuantitiyDictionary = null)
    {
        return ViewComponent(typeof(CartComponent), productQuantitiyDictionary);
    }
```

---

```
reloadCartComponent() {
    var dict = {};
    dict["443597a5-9940-49a8-94d5-3c386e9e6fd1"] = 1;
    dict["4b27e0b7-6617-4ba2-b8aa-94751b3d9a7a"] = 2;
    

    $.ajax({
        url: "Products/UpdateCart",
        data: {
            productQuantitiyDictionary : dict
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#summary").html(data);
        }
    })
}
```